# How to get the note and its velocity from MIDI event?

Tags: midi, web-midi

I can parse a MIDI file using the `midi-parser-js` [library](https://github.com/colxi/midi-parser-js)

and create a `soundtrack` object containing all the tracks and their events:

```
export class Soundtrack {
  name: string;
  duration: number;
  tracks: Array<Track>;
}
export class Track {
  events: Array<MidiEvent>;
}
export class MidiEvent {
  data: any;
  deltaTime: number;
  metaType: number;
  type: number;
}
```

I also have a working synth service to which I'd like to feed these MIDI notes:

```
synth.triggerAttack(note, null, velocity);
synth.triggerRelease(note);
```

How to filter the MIDI events that are notes ?

How to get the actual note and its velocity from such a MIDI event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the notes are read from the file:

```
....
MIDI.track[t-1].event[e-1].type = parseInt(statusByte[0], 16);// first byte is EVENT TYPE ID
MIDI.track[t-1].event[e-1].channel = parseInt(statusByte[1], 16);// second byte is channel
...
switch(MIDI.track[t-1].event[e-1].type){
...
case 0x8:                                               // Note off
case 0x9:                                               // Note On
    MIDI.track[t-1].event[e-1].data = [];
    MIDI.track[t-1].event[e-1].data[0] = file.readInt(1);
    MIDI.track[t-1].event[e-1].data[1] = file.readInt(1);
```

First `data` byte is the note number, second byte is the velocity.

Comment: I'm still trying to parse it, notably to see if I can get measures from it.

Comment: Each measure can have a tempo and a time signature.

Comment: In MIDI files, tempo or time signate can change at any time.

Comment: I found the specification https://github.com/colxi/midi-parser-js/wiki/MIDI-File-Format-Specifications

Comment: You wouldn't have the event parsing method feeding explicitly named variables ? So as to save me a week's effort. For example; in the type 9 event, which part of data is the note number and which is the velocity ?

Comment: To create an abc note with its duration, I need to consider two consecutive events of types 9 and 8 and use the delta time of the second one to calculate the duration of the note ?